# How Do I Calculate the Number of Weekday Between Two Dates in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I only need the difference of Weekdays, NOT weekends

Here is my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT
created_time_receiving [1] :: DATE - created_time_order_items :: DATE AS days
FROM order_items
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isodow` function:

> The day of the week as Monday(1) to Sunday(7)

Combinated to the `generate_series(start, stop, step)` function:

> Generate a series of values, from **start** to **stop** with a step size of **step**

To make this query:

```
SELECT
  count(*) AS days
FROM
  generate_series('2021-02-02', '2021-06-02', interval '1d') d
WHERE
  extract('isodow' FROM d) < 6;
```

Comment: SELECT
    (
        created_time_receiving [1] :: DATE - created_time_order_items :: DATE,
        INTERVAL '1d'
    ) AS days extract(
        isodow
        FROM
            order_items
    ) < 6; But I getting the error: Query 1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "extract"
LINE 6:     ) AS days extract(

Comment: Oups, I had forgotten the `' '` around `isodow`, I've edited the answer.

Comment: This is my SQL Statement: SELECT
    (
        created_time_receiving [1] :: DATE - created_time_order_items :: DATE,
        INTERVAL '1d'
    ) AS days extract(
        'isodow'
        FROM
            order_items
    ) < 6;  ------------- But when I run yours it's fine, can you please check why it's not working on my database?

Comment: Your `created_time_receiving [1] :: DATE` format is really strange. From where are coming the 2 dates used in your request ? (`created_time_receiving ` and `created_time_order_items `).

Comment: It's an "Array" field, & this is why I need to format it & convert it as a Date , it's coming from Another table   ----- Any field type that can contain more than one item will be represented in your Postgres database as an array of `text` values.

Comment: It's an array field, in your database ? or in your code ? In both cases, I don't know how to help you... Maybe try creating a new question in StackOverflow